# Receive a response from Webservice and interpret it in AngularJS

Tags: .net, html, angularjs, web-services, asmx

how are you?

I've got a simple question. I have the following msg return in my webservice (asmx):

```
msg = "~/Paginas/Home.aspx";
row.Add("Retorno", msg);
rows.Add(row);
Context.Response.Output.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows));
return;
```

I'm using it to validate a login page in AngularJS + HTML5.
My question is, how could I get this message on HTML side and interpret it to make the redirect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the webservice expose any RESTful routes, such that you could do a `POST` using angular's `$http` service? (edit: guess it doesn't have to be RESTful really, any POSTable route would be fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you send a json object through the wire, something like:

**on the server side:**

```
var returnInfo = new { Message = '/paginas/home.aspx' };
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return serializer.Serialize(returnInfo);
```

**on the client side:**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource','$window'
        function($scope, $resource, $window) {
            var myEndPoint = $resource('/myEndpoint/Url');
            myEndPoint.$get(function(data){
                if(data.message){
                    $window.location.href = data.message ; // if you plan to do a full page refresh
                }
            );

        }
    ]);
```

that's the general idea to do it, I hope that helps!

cheers!

Comment: I already have a controller in my form called FormCTRL, can I set two controllers to the same form in Angular? How can I do that?

Comment: @LucasLira no use the one you have, I'm just trying to give you an idea of a possible approach you can take, the concept in a nutshell is to return an anonymous object serialize to JSON, pass the message to your client if you got a message do a redirect with  the $window object

Comment: post your controller if you want